# proper use google webmaster tools URL Parameters

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, google-search-console, googlebot

There are some urls like `http://domain.com/user/:username` and `http://domain.com/post/:id` on my website, the username and id is the parameter from database.
I try to let google crawler more efficiently , can I use `google webmaster tools > URL Parameters > add parameter` ? I read the document but still don't get it how to set up?
the column `Parameter` and the rest what should I filled? or this tools only for `get` method parameter?
[image]     [image]